# how to select the table name which is created from the argument of a function in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I  created a table in a function by getting the argument as a name of the table, as a continuation of the function I have to select and also update the same table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mnth
(
    tablename text
    folder_path text
)
RETURNS void as $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format ( 
        'CREATE TABLE %I.%I
        (
         row_id text,
         left_row text,
         right_row text,
         left_plus text
        )' , 'monthly',tablename 
    );

    INSERT INTO edmonton.rid_pid
    SELECT 
        row_id,
        SPLIT_PART (row_id, '-',1) as left_may,
        SPLIT_PART (row_id, '-',2) as right_may
    FROM  '%I.%I','monthly',tablename ;

    UPDATE '%I.%I','monthly',tablename
        SET left_plus = left_row:: integer +1 ;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to know how to get the function argument for select and update query

Comment: In the same way that you **execute**d your create statement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here you need to have a procedure instead of a function (if you need nothing out of your function, it seems better). (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html) (Postgresql 11 only)

If you want to know about the format function : 
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-format/

Maybe this code is what you need (or close enough to it)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mnth
(
    tablename text
)  LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$
declare query varchar;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format ( 
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s.%s
        (
         row_id text,
         left_row text,
         right_row text,
         left_plus text
        )', 'monthly',cast(tablename as varchar)
    );

    query := 'INSERT INTO edmonton.rid_pid
    SELECT 
        row_id,
        cast(SPLIT_PART(row_id, ''-'',1) as varchar) as left_may,
        cast(SPLIT_PART (row_id, ''-'',2) as varchar) as right_may
    FROM  monthly.test;';
    execute query;
    query := 'UPDATE monthly.'||tablename||'
        SET left_plus = left_row::integer +1;';
    execute query;
END;
$$;

-- to call it
call mnth(cast('test' as text));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I do so, there was an error " too few arguments for format()" it was occuring